# Limit a value in SQL

Tags: sql

Not that familiar with SQL.

I have the follow SQL :

```
UPDATE my_Table 
SET num = num + 1 
WHERE id = 1
```

I would like limit that `num` column that it won't exceed a threshold, assuming 100. If `num` will reach 100, I would like it to stay 100 and will not increase.

I assume if statement should be included here somehow. but cant figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE my_Table 
SET num = CASE WHEN num+1 >= 100 THEN 100 ELSE num+1 END
WHERE id=1
```

Comment: considering the other options, what is the best approach ?

Comment: when the row finally hits 100, why would you bother to UPDATE it to the same 100 value every time.

Comment: @Lamak, OP never says what starting values may or may not be.

Comment: @KM. yeah, so?. It's exactly as you said, op never clarified what starting values may or may not be. I chose a solution with the assumption written in my comment. It's as easy as adding a `AND num <> 99`

Comment: @Lamak, where is your code assuming that the first value should be 1? what if the initial value is negative, what if the initial value is NULL?

Comment: ??, what does any of that matter?. The only requirement was to limit `num` to 100. Stop adding requirements or write a question yourself

Comment: @Lamak, ha, you made up the requirement to lower an initial value that is over 100 back to 100

Comment: @KM. no, I didn't made up any requirement at all. Can you read?, `If num will reach 100, I would like it to stay 100 and will not increase.` seems pretty clear to me

Comment: @Lamak . That worked perfectly and exactly what I needed .. thanks !

Comment: @Lamak, thanks for the concern, I can read, and write too! To me "reach 100", implies it is incrementing there, not already there.

Comment: @KM. yeah, sorry, my comment was out of place

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing answers that would solve your problem from an update statement, all fine whatever way it is done.

Until someone creates a statement that doesn't adhere to your constraint, like a new co-worker, someone sleepy that forgets it or whatever reason. You should probably know about other options to force this rule.

You could create an [SQL constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_constraints.asp) that checks that `num` is never set to more than 100. That way any update or insert statement that makes this value more than 100 would result in an error rather than doing the insert or update.

Another way to force this rule "under the hood", not really beginner level, would be to create an update and insert trigger that would check for `num` being more than 100 and reset it to 100 in that case. That wouldn't result in an error when you run the insert or update statement. I don't have a good link for ANSI-SQL triggers, but each RDBMS has good documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I was explicitly after the solution of not having an error when update. because I may update other things as well in the same SQL statement.

Comment: I'll add another way to do it "I forgot it"-proof. Just for completeness' sake, probably not beginner level.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
UPDATE my_Table SET num=num+1 WHERE id=1 AND num<=99
```

Comment: But if `num` is already a value over 100, it will keep that value instead of limiting it to 100

Comment: @Lamak, the OP is fairly vague on how that should work and what the current values are.  I'd prefer to only UPDATE a row when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

in that case you can use IIF for shorter version

```
    UPDATE my_Table SET num=(IIF((num+1)>100,num,num+1)) WHERE id=1
```